# Pivot query with TOTAL

Tags: mysql

Need help again.

I have this query to pivot a table as shown:

```
    SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT
CASE WHEN ISNULL(country) THEN 'APAC' ELSE country END AS COUNTRY,
IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(calldate)=1 THEN duration END),'---') AS 'Jan16',
 IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(calldate)=2 THEN duration END),'---') AS 'Feb16',
  IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(calldate)=3 THEN duration END),'---') AS 'Mar16',
   IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(calldate)=4 THEN duration END),'---') AS 'Apr16',
    IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(calldate)=5 THEN duration END),'---') AS 'May16',
     IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(calldate)=6 THEN duration END),'---') AS 'Jun16',
      IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(calldate)=7 THEN duration END),'---') AS 'Jul16',
       IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(calldate)=8 THEN duration END),'---') AS 'Aug16',
        IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(calldate)=9 THEN duration END),'---') AS 'Sept16',
         IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(calldate)=10 THEN duration END),'---') AS 'Oct16',
          IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(calldate)=11 THEN duration END),'---') AS 'Nov16',
           IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(calldate)=12 THEN duration END),'---') AS 'Dec16',
IFNULL((SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(calldate)=11 THEN duration END)-
SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(calldate)=12 THEN duration END)),'---') AS 'BW'
FROM
(SELECT cdr_users.`parts`,cdr.*, cdr_users.`country` FROM cdr LEFT JOIN cdr_users ON cdr.dst = cdr_users.`parts`
WHERE (CHAR_LENGTH(dst)=6 AND LEFT(dst, 3) IN ('123','124','125','126'))
AND (calldate >=  '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND calldate <= '2016-12-31 23:59:59')) AS cdr 
GROUP BY country WITH ROLLUP
) AS cdr1
```

Now the result is this:
[image]
Issue:

As you can see, the Bottom row is showing the TOTALS just fine, HOWEVER, the name is still APAC.
THis is because of the 1st CASE statement. How can I change that to TOTAL instead of APAC leaving the 1st row as APAC?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to handle this in application code?

Comment: yes. :) this is a test query. then ill do it in app code to make it dynamic. i needed to see how to logic works in query.

Comment: Then I fear you're confusing data retrieval and data display

Comment: I'll take your advise. But, since we're here, is there anyway to do it through query though?